# LINQ to PostgreSQL: query varchar[] column with ilike condition

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I has a table in PostgreSQL 9.6.6 database with a column of array type:

```
create table public.account (
  user_name character varying(120), -- login
  emails character varying(200)[] -- array of emails of account
)
```

I need to query that table on emails, where at least one email contains given string: if where is a record with **emails = '{admin@mail.com,su@mail.com,owner@mail.com}'** and I'm searching for **'admin'**, this record should be selected.

It can be done for PostgreSQL using query

```
select * from public.account
where 0 < (select count(1) from unnest(emails) as e where upper(e) like '%ADMIN%');
```

In a C# (.NET Core 6) project a have a class for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6

```
internal class Account
{
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

and corresponding dataset in DataContext:

```
internal class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

But there is no equivalent for such query in LINQ. I've tried

```
var email = "admin".ToUpper();
var accounts = dataContext.Accounts.Where(a => a.Emails.Any(e => e.ToUpper().Contains(email))).ToArray();
```

and that should be translated exact to the same SQL query - but is does not:

> The LINQ expression 'e => e.ToUpper().Contains(__email_0)' could not
> be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
> more information.

The only thing that works in my case is

```
var email = "admin".ToUpper();
var accounts = dataContext.Accounts.Where(a => String.Join(',', a.Emails).ToUpper().Contains(email)).ToArray();
```

which translates into

```
-- @__email_0='ADMIN'
SELECT a.user_name, a.emails
FROM account AS a
WHERE (@__email_0 = '') OR (strpos(upper(array_to_string(a.emails, ',', '')), @__email_0) > 0)
```

That gives me similar, but not exact **the same** result I tried to get.

I can make the field in database to be jsonb type, but I think the problem still exists: there is no way to create C# LINQ query I need.

So the question is what is the right way to create C# LINQ query that gives me table records where array field (column of PostgreSQL array type) has at least one element that corresponds **ilike** condition?

Comment: Which EF to PostgreSQL provider are you using?

Comment: All project dependencies are: 

<PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />

<PackageReference Include="EFCore.NamingConventions" Version="6.0.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="6.0.0" />

<PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="6.0.1" />

<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.1" />


<PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.2.14" />

Comment: According to the Npgsql docs, you should use `array.Any(s => EF.Functions.ILike(string, s))`. Docs: https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html

Comment: I've tried. That is about using ilike for string column filtering. String, not an array of strings.

Comment: This would be "The LINQ expression 's => ... " error.